# How do I parse diskstats and output in JSON format with shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

With a bash script, I am trying to get all of the physical disks from /proc/diskstats

```
   8       0 sda 14256 20634 1376722 133628 279800 2362075 21135024 2133492 0 261052 2259536
   8       1 sda1 14105 20634 1375514 133520 279800 2362075 21135024 2133492 0 261036 2259432
   2       0 fd0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and echo their names in a format such as

```
{
  "data":[
  { "{#DISK}":"sda"},
  { "{#DISK}":"sdb"},
  ]
}
```

I am trying to do this in such a way that will be supported by systems with Linux 2.6+. I also want to avoid partitions that may show up in diskstats, which have 4 fields instead of the 11 for disks.

EDIT:

I can get disk names with

```
cat /proc/diskstats | awk '{print $3}'
```

or

```
cat /proc/diskstats | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

but I'm not sure how to iterate through and format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming none of your device names have double quotes in them (trollface.jpg), you can stick to awk for this.

```
BEGIN {
  print "{"
  printf "  \"data\": ["
  first=1
}

!first {
  printf ","
}

NF == 14 {
  printf "\n  { \"{#DISK}\":\""$3"\"}"
  first=0
}

END {
  print "\n  ]"
  print "}"
}
```

Comment: I was on my way with `cat /proc/diskstats | awk '{print "\"{#DISK}\":\"$3\""}'` but the $3 wasn't being treated as a variable, but as text "$3". Of course the JSON doesn't have to be pretty printed :) Could you hint me to awk's syntax if I want to pipe something to that because I'm struggling with errors that are related to that being over multiple lines. Nevermind, silly mistake here.

Comment: I just put it in a file and use `-f` to run it.